# Swift Array multiple appending on click

Tags: arrays, swift, append

I'm creating a button that when clicked adds the current date and time to an array but when I try to append to the array it only appends once and not repeating the process

the Entries struct:

```
struct Enteries {

    var dates:[String] = []
}
```

convert date to String:

```
func DateConverter(){    
    format.timeZone = .current
    format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    dateString = format.string(from: currentDate)
}
```

The function that appends:  also its called later whenever an IBAction is triggered

```
func AddToDatabase () {
    var entery = Enteries()

    entery.dates.append(dateString)
    print(entery.dates)


}
```

`

Comment: From [what I can find](https://www.askdifference.com/entery-vs-entry/) "Entery" is an obsolete spelling, it's just "Entry". Also, I caution the use of the name `Enteries`, which implies that the one struct models multiple enteries. I would expect such a struct to have a `var entries: [Entry]` property, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating a new entery object eveytime the function is called. SO its creating a new object everytime. Declare your entery object outside the function.

```
var entery = Enteries()
func AddToDatabase () {

        entery.dates.append(dateString)
        print(entery.dates)


    }
```

Comment: Yes That is what i did exactly and it worked i placed the entery object outside the function

Answer (score 3):

Yikes, there's a lot going on here.

- First of all, Swift's convention is to use `lowerCamelCase` for functions. Only type names should be `UpperCamelCase`.
- Secondly, function names should be verbs or verb phrases, type names should be nouns. If I saw `DateConverter` in some code, I would expect it to be a type. It's an `UpperCamelCase` noun, that's how types should be named. But yours is a function (which would be a total surprise to every other Swift developer, because it violates the expectations they've built up from Swift's naming conventions), that function should probably be called `parseDate`.
- Which way does `DateConverter` convert? From `String` to `Date`, `Date` to `String`, or both? What's its input? What's it's output? These things should be obvious from a good function name, but are totally unknown here without looking at the implementation.
- Critically, the `DateConverter` function doesn't take input from parameters, and doesn't return a result, instead it takes input from a side effect (accessing the variable `currentDate`) and returns a result via side effect (writing to an a variable `dateString`). This is really bad, for several reasons:

  - It's not reusable. You have no way to use this date parsing code somewhere else without copy/pasting it, which is how code duplication and complexity arise. If you ever decide to change the date format in your app, you won't have a central source-of-truth that you can change, instead you'll have to manually hunt down every copy of this function, and change it, hoping you don't miss any. Not good.
  - It's not thread safe
  - It's more complex than a simple function that has type `(Date) -> String`. It obfuscates what's going on.
  - It defies peoples' expectations, without justification.
- `Enteries.dates` has a default value of `[]`, which doesn't seem to be a good idea if you're going to be appending to it as soon as you create it. Instead, take the array via an initializer parameter.

  - `Enteries.dates` has type `[String]`. Why?! You already have `Date` objects, store those!
  - They're smaller (in memory)
  - They're presentation-agnostic, meaning you can properly format them for different interfaces and different locales at a later time, as necessary
  - They support date math. I often see people storing dates as strings, and ask questions like "How do I sort my array of dates?" (which are actually stored as strings), "How do I add 1 day to `"2019-12-24`", and they start doing funky parsing, splitting, joining, and it's all just an absolute mess

Here's how I would improve this code:

```
struct Entries {
    var entries: [Entry]
}

struct Entry {
    let date: Date
}

// Call this from your view layer, only when you're about to present a `Date` to a user.
func parse(date: Date) -> String {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.timeZone = .current
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    return format.string(from: currentDate)
}

var entries = Entries(entries: [])

func addToDatabase(entry: Entry) {
    entries.append(entry)
    print(enteries.entries)
}
```